# How to remove . values from a data set in R?

Tags: r

[image]

How to remove the . values from this dataset?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what format your dataset is but I am just going to assume it is csv, try this when loading your dataset:

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv", na.strings=".")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. When you read the dataset, you can use argument like:`na.string = "."`
2. mutate "." into NA. `dplyr::mutate_all(temp3,~ifelse(.x == ".",NA,.x))`

Answer (score 0):

A *data.table* solution:

Convert the table to data.table

```
temp3 = data.table(temp3)
temp3 = temp3[CBBTCUSD != '.']
```

If you have multiple types of characters to remove then

```
temp3 = temp3[!(CBBTCUSD %in% c('.','','. ',' .'))]
```